# What exactly are Jessica Jones' powers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, powers, jessica-jones-2015, jessica-jones

As far as I can recall, on the Netflix *Jessica Jones* TV series,  she had only exhibited super strength and super toughness.  Does she have any other powers?

## What exactly are Jessica Jones' powers in the MCU?

Comment: @Himarm, I consider all basic physical abilities to be aspects of the same.

Comment: @CandiedMango, except not always. ..

Comment: Like most of her powers she's not very good at using it.

Comment: Is f__ing s#!t up a power?

Comment: Most people seem to possess it.

Comment: Drinking all around the clock without serious hangover. That is simply INHUMAN!

Answer (score 18):

She has four powers: super strength, fast healing, increased durability (is there a better term for 'more durable than humans, but not invincible'?), and some mild form of flight.

We see her use the super strength more than any other power.  Usually to get around pesky locks.

She comments at one point that she doesn't need to worry too much about some injuries due to her healing faster than normal people do.

She lacks invulnerability, but is slightly more durable than a normal human.  We see this over and over again in the show, as she easily gets cut or wounded from gunshots.  But we see that she doesn't hurt herself using super strength, so she's a bit more able to take damage than humans.

In the comics, she can fly, she's just unpracticed, so she's not good at it.  In the show, we see her make superhuman jumps a few times, so it's unclear if in the show she can actually fly, or if she just uses her super strength to jump far.

Comment: She mentions several times in the show that "it's not flying, it's more like jumping".

Comment: @Philipp: Still, could be she later discovers there's a flying component of it that she hasn't tapped yet. Clark in Smallville was in this situation for years, for example.

Comment: "she doesn't hurt herself using super strength, so she's a bit more able to take damage than humans" -- that could be a special case though: maybe if she punches a board she takes less damage to her knuckles than if the same board is smashed over her fist with identical force. Because of, for the sake of argument, her use of Chi or something. You have to be cautious about generalising the specific properties that a superhero *appears* to have been given just to make their other powers usable.

Comment: @SteveJessop We actually see her falling at least 5-6 floors (it might be more but high enough to kill a regular person) hugging a guy who falls onto her and walk away after it, so I think she is definitely more durable than regular people.

Comment: Jessica appears to have little to no actual combat training, but has enough innate resilience to take a number of tazes before finally succumbing. Trish, who is fairly well trained, goes down in one shot.

Comment: Re flight, even in the show she once mentions "directed falling", so I think it safe to say that, as in the comics, she has some level of actual flight but isn't very good at it.

Comment: @mg30rg If you're referring to the scene at the end of episode 3, I'm pretty sure she faked that. She needed to convince the cop that he jumped, she didn't actually need to do it.

Comment: @svick What makes you think she faked that? We hear a huge banging sound and they are covered in bruises and minor wounds. I think we didn't see the actual falling because of the khmm... _moderate_ budget of the show, not because it was fake. Also, we see her power jumping (flying?) away with the unconscious body of Killgrave, and the impact of that jump also has to be bone-breaking.

Comment: @mg30rg Actually, if you watch the scene again we see her standing up next to the bin bags and just falling into them while holding Will. It's obvious that she faked it in-universe.

Comment: No fly! Jump good!

Answer (score 10):

Excluding her physical abilities which you've already mentioned (notably her durability and physical strength), Jessica Jones has shown three other abilities in the show thus far:

### **Flight** (kinda)

Although Jessica doesn't appear to be able to fly at the start of the show, this interview with showrunner Melissa Rosenberg would suggest that her abilities are growing and may eventually evolve into true flight:

> "She doesn't fly but she can jump many stories, and she lands really
>   badly, which is why she doesn't do it too often," Rosenberg says. "And
>   the less you see it, the more believable it is. There will be flights
>   in every episode and they'll get bigger and bigger and bigger but
>   that's not my priority. That's not the nature of the story. This show
>   is more character driven than anything like a scene in that universe."

### Super-healing

During the series Jessica suffers a gunshot, several broken ribs and numerous smaller cuts and contusions. Within days she seems to be fit and ready for action with no obvious scarring or permanent damage:

> **Jessica:** *It's fine. It's just ribs. I heal faster than most. You know that.*
>
> **Trish:** *You'll heal wrong if you're not careful.*

### Resistance to Kilgrave

A key element of the show is that Jessica is uniquely qualified to tackle Kilgrave...

> ... because of her ability to resist the mind-control virus that he exudes.

She specifically states;

> **Jessica:** *They're dead! And there's nothing that I can do about that. But I can rip Kilgrave's throat out. You saw what happened, and
>  **I'm immune to him.***

Comment: That's a really big spoiler at the end there...are spoiler tags supported on this site?

Comment: @TimB  - I've retagged it. I'm not really certain how necessary it is, but I'm happy to err on the side of caution

Comment: Well I'd figured it out by the time she went to stay with him that she was resistant but it was still a pretty big moment when she figured it out.

Comment: Even the heading of the last point is a massive Spoiler and not something known until very late into the show run

Comment: @user001 - We find out that she's *resistant* in the first or second episode. We don't find out the details until about episode 6

Comment: Yes @Richard, and the implication is that anyone could develop a resistance after they are forced to do something which is anathama to their core beliefs.

Comment: @MarkBooth - Jessica is the only person who has any resistance as far as I can recall. Even Kilgrave's parents (who'd lived under his yoke for *years*) were unable to resist commands to hurt and kill themselves.

Comment: @Richard we find out that she is resistant but no one (except Kilgrave) realises it. That reveal occurs after episode 7.

Comment: @user001 - We see her resist his commands in the first episode (when he gets hit by the truck). It is, admittedly only until later that we understand his power and realise (courtesy of a flashback for those that weren't paying enough attention) that her refusal to immediately obey shows her resistance.